# Como acessar apenas uma celula numa lista dentro de uma lista

Tags: python

Estou a fazer um codigo para inicializar uma grelha de sudoku em que o n^2 é o tamanho do tabuleiro e alpha a percentagem de celulas que vao ser preenchidas.
Porém quando tento alterar apenas uma celula em questao, a coluna toda é alterada e nao sei como resolver

```
import random
def inicializagrelha(n,alpha): 

if alpha <= 0 or alpha > 1: 
    return "Error" 
numeropreencher = 0
numeropreencher = round((n**4) * alpha) 
grelha = []
listaux = []
for k in range(n * n):
    listaux.append(0)
    grelha.append(listaux)

count = 0
celulaspreenchidas = []

while(count < numeropreencher):
    aux = random.randint(1,n**4)
    if aux not in celulaspreenchidas: 
        celulaspreenchidas.append(aux)
        linha = 0
        for j in range(n**2): 
            for lista in grelha: 
                if linha == j: 
                    if aux <= j*(n**2) and -aux+(j*(n**2))<9:
                        lista[-aux+(j*(n**2))] = 2
                    else: 
                        linha += 1
        count += 1
    else: 
        aux = random.randint(1,n**4)
        
return grelha
```

Comment: Para acessar uma lista de listas, você precisa de dois índices. `ll = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]]`. Para alterar o segundo item da segunda lista, basta `ll[1][1] = 44`.

Answer (score 0):

Já descobri, basta mudar

```py
grelha = []
listaux = []
for k in range(n * n):
    listaux.append(0)
    grelha.append(listaux)

#Para 
grelha = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).